# How to encode one or multiple categorical variables into one feature

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, categorical-data

I am trying to train a machine learning model on some categorical data I have, however I am unsure how to encode it. If I have a table like the following, what is the best way to encode "var_3"?

```
| var_1 | var_2 | var_3                                             |
|-------|-------|---------------------------------------------------|
| 32    | 0     | 'attribute_1'                                     |
| 15    | 1     | 'attribute_1,attribute_2,attribute_3,attribute_4' |
```

Is it a good idea to encode each "attribute" individually into an integer? Like the following:

```
| var_1 | var_2 | var_3 |
|-------|-------|-------|
| 32    | 0     | 1     |
| 15    | 1     | 1234  |
```

Or is it better to encode each possible combination of attributes into an integer?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to encode as binary column for each attribute in var_3. So:

```
   var1  var_2                            var_3   attr_1  attr_2  attr_3  attr_4
0    32      0                          'attr_1'       1       0       0       0
1    15      1  'attr_1, attr_2, attr_3, attr_4'       1       1       1       1
```

And delete `var_3` before feeding dataframe to the model.